# rendering video on a texture in LibGDX

Tags: android, video, textures, libgdx

i am new to LibGDX
i'm building a game and i have an animated background that has about 10 seconds of animation (250 frames aprox.) since it's useless to try and build a sprite sheet for this (large background of course) is there a way to render video files are png sequence to a texture so i can have my animated background drawn in the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now an extension for video playback [gdx-video](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-video).

Comment: this library is not working/available now, do you any library which available and works now.

Answer (score 1):

If your idea is to put a texture on background and render the image and timely replace it to give the animation frame, then a good start is having a look here: [How to draw a texture into a quad with OpenGL ES 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422523/how-to-draw-a-texture-into-a-quad-with-opengl-es-2)

Answer (score -1):

I is the way to play,  libname is "indiespot-media-0.8.09.jar"  [site](http://indiespot.net/files/projects/medialib/)

How to use:

1. dowload full zip
2. copy lib folder in the root of proj (ffmpeg will be opened by lib with path ./lib/ffmpeg/ffmpeg@os postfix@)
3. ```
   player = new MoviePlayer(videoFile);
   Texure playerTexture = new Texture(player.movie.width(), player.movie.height(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888) {
     @Override
     public void bind() {
         Gdx.gl.glBindTexture(0, player.textureHandle);
     }
   };
   ```
4. use playerTexture as usual texture

Comment: What does exactly statement 4 mean?