# Little Movies in 2d games

Tags: graphics, libgdx, graphics2d, game-development

I wanted to know, whats the best way to create scenes in games, like little movies playbacks.
I am using libgdx and i tried creating em using animation frames but it is a bit difficult.
Is there any better way?

Comment: Check out this question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30607/play-videos-with-libgdx

Comment: And maybe on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468091/rendering-video-on-a-texture-in-libgdx